# How to convert list of string into list of number then apply OrderByDescending on that list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Consider this as the values in column `Emp_code`.
E1000
E1001
E9000
E4000
E1339
E10000

I'm using this code to first remove the E from all of the occurrences than convert them into number than apply `OrderByDescending` to the `list`.

```
var idd = db?.HRMS_EmpMst_TR?.Where(a => a.Emp_code != null)? 
.Select(x=>x.Emp_code.Remove(0,1)).Select(int.Parse).OrderByDescending(y => y).First();
```

Can somebody help me with this code. I want to get 10000 as the answer.
**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: Use SubString : .Select(x=> int.Parse(x.SubString(1))).OrderByDescending(y => y).First();

Comment: If all the numbers after "E" have 4 digits, then the string will have the desired order without converting to number. If the number of digits vary, then convert to a number type.

Comment: @jdweng, we can use `Max()` instead of `OrderByDescending().First()`? What do you think?

Comment: Only if the length of the number are the same.  A string sort would be like this 1,10,100,2,20,200,3,30,300.

Comment: *Can somebody help me with this code.* -- Where do you need help? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: It looks like your code works fine. Is there any specific error or output you are getting with this Linq? I just suggested an improvement in your code.

Comment: Digits are not the same in length all the time that's why I was converting it into number. @PrasadTelkikar I will try your code than I'll let you know. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say so, but I think you are working with a database, so you are working IQueryable, and not IEnumerable. This means that you can't use methods like String.TrimStart nor String.Parse.

So you have something called `db`, of which you didn't bother to tell us what it is. I assume it is a DbContext or something similar to access a database management system.

This DbContext has a table `HRMS_EmpMst_TR`, filled with rows of which I don't know what they are (please, next time give us some more information!). What I do know, that there are no null rows in this table. So your `Where` is meaningless.

By the way, are you not certain that db is not null?

```
if (db == null) return null;
```

After this, we know that `db.HRMS_EmpMst_TR` is a non null possible empty sequence of rows, where every row has a string column `EmpCode`. Every EmpCode starts with the character `E` followed by a four digits number. You want the EmpCode with the largest number.

```
string largestEmpCode = db.HRMS_EmpMst_TR
    .OrderByDescending(row => row.EmpCode)
    .Select(row => row.EmpCode)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

You get the string `E9000`, or null, if the table is empty. If you want `9000` just remove the first character and parse. What do you want if the table is empty?

```
if (largestEmpCode != null)
{
    int largestEmpCodeValue = Int32.Parse(largestEmpCode.SubString(1));
}
else
{
    // TODO: handle empty table.
}
```

### There is room for improvement

If you are certain that every EmpCode is the character `E` followed by a four digit number, and you want to do calculations with this number, consider to change the EmpCode column to an integer column, without the `E`. This is a one time action, and it will make future calculations much easier.

Database column:

```
int EmpCodeValue;
```

LINQ to get the largest EmpCodeValue:

```
int largestEmpCodeValue = db.HRMS_EmpMst_TR
    .Select(row => row.EmpCodeValue)
    .Max();
```

If other parts of your application really need an "E followed by four digits", you can always make an extension method. I don't know what HRMS_EmpMst_TR are, let's assume it is a table of `EmpMst`

```
public string GetEmpCode(this EmpMst empMst)
{
    return String.Format("E{0,04}", empMst.EmpCode);
}
```

I'm not sure about the `,04` part. You'll have to look it up, how to convert integer 4 to string "0004"

Usage:

```
List<EmpMst> fetchedEmpMsts  = ...
string firstEmpCode = fetchedEmpMsts[0].GetEmpCode();
```

Or:

```
var result = db.HRMS_EmpMst_TR
    .Where(empMst => empMst.Name == ...) // or use some other filter, just an example
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(empMst => new
    {
        Id = empMst.Id,
        Name = empMst.Name,
        EmpCode = empMst.GetEmpCode(),
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to

1. Use [`TrimStart('E')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-5.0#System_String_TrimStart_System_Char_) to remove E char from each string and parse it to
   integer.
2. Get [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=3.0-,Max(IEnumerable%3E),sequence%20of%20nullable%20Int32%20values.) value from the processed sequence.

```
var input = new List<string>(){"E1000", "E1001", "E9000", "E4000", "E1339"};
var result = input
      .Select(x => int.Parse(x.TrimStart('E'))) //Remove E and then parse string to integer  
      .Max(); //Get max value from an IEnumerable
```

Try Online: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GGYQP6)

Comment: Be aware, this solution will only work on IEnumerable, not IQueryable. So if you want to use entity framework or something similar, you can't use this solution

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse, I completely agree with you. You covered everything. +1 to you. M.HassanNasir, If you are working with a database(it looks like from you Linq) then please follow Harald's answer, he suggested a very good improvement to make your employee code column as an integer type.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. :)